# refactor duplicate code - only difference is a < sign

Tags: c#, polymorphism

Class Test is `abstract`. It contains a basic testname and a score. This score (double) is accessible through a property named TestScore.

Three kind of classes inherit from Test. They are as such different that each kind of test has a different way of rating a score.

**Aim**: Rate a score with one of 6 ratings based on a range of values in between of which the score can be.

```
class ScoreRangeAscendingTest : Test
{
    public ScoreRangeAscendingTest(double score, Enums.TestType typeName) : base(score, typeName) { }
    public double[] ranges;
    public Enums.Rating calculateScore(double[] range)
    {
        if (scoreInVeryWeakRange())
            return Enums.Rating.VeryWeak;
        else if (scoreInWeakRange())
            return Enums.Rating.Weak;
        else if (scoreInAveragelyWeakRange())
            return Enums.Rating.AveragelyWeak;
        else if (scoreInAveragelyGoodRange())
            return Enums.Rating.AveragelyGood;
        else if (scoreInGoodRange())
            return Enums.Rating.Good;
        else 
            return Enums.Rating.VeryGood;
    }

    private bool scoreInVeryWeakRange()
    {
        return this.TestScore < ranges[(int)Enums.Border.P10];
    }
    private bool scoreInWeakRange()
    {
        return TestScore >= ranges[(int)Enums.Border.P10] && TestScore < ranges[(int)Enums.Border.P25];
    }
    private bool scoreInAveragelyWeakRange()
    {
        return TestScore >= ranges[(int)Enums.Border.P25] && TestScore < ranges[(int)Enums.Border.P50];
    }
    private bool scoreInAveragelyGoodRange()
    {
        return TestScore >= ranges[(int)Enums.Border.P50] && TestScore < ranges[(int)Enums.Border.P75];
    }
    private bool scoreInGoodRange()
    {
        return TestScore >= ranges[(int)Enums.Border.P75] && TestScore < ranges[(int)Enums.Border.P90];
    }
    private bool scoreInVeryGoodRange()
    {
        return TestScore > ranges[(int)Enums.Border.P90];
    }

}
```

}

**The problem**: I have tests whose corresponding ranges go up and tests whose corresponding ranges go down. So I need to write the exact same code for the second type of test, but this time, all the '<' signs need to be '>' signs and vice versa.

**Question**: how can I avoid duplicating this code? is there a possibility to add it to the base class?

Comment: It would be helpful to include the test code which is duplicated; the code here that the test calls doesn't tell us much.

Comment: what is duplicated is the list of private bool functions - the only difference in each case is the < becoming > and vice versa.

The solution has been given :-)

Comment: I don't understand your question then. The code you posted is not the same except for < becoming >.

Comment: check the answers given by others
The idea is to inject the function of smaller than or greater than into a function based on what kind of a class an object is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I get the question, but you might be able to use a delegate to perform the comparison.

The following should be equivalent to your current code:

```
class ScoreRangeAscendingTest : Test
{
    public ScoreRangeAscendingTest(double score, Enums.TestType typeName) : base(score, typeName) { }
    public double[] ranges;
    public Enums.Rating calculateScore(double[] range) {
        Func<double, double, bool> cmp = (x, y) => x < y; // you can swap the comparison here, e.g. (x, y) => x > y
        if (scoreInVeryWeakRange(cmp))
            return Enums.Rating.VeryWeak;
        else if (scoreInWeakRange(cmp))
            return Enums.Rating.Weak;
        else if (scoreInAveragelyWeakRange(cmp))
            return Enums.Rating.AveragelyWeak;
        else if (scoreInAveragelyGoodRange(cmp))
            return Enums.Rating.AveragelyGood;
        else if (scoreInGoodRange(cmp))
            return Enums.Rating.Good;
        else 
            return Enums.Rating.VeryGood;
    }

    private bool scoreInVeryWeakRange(Func<double, double, bool> cmp)
    {
        return cmp(this.TestScore, ranges[(int)Enums.Border.P10]);
    }
    private bool scoreInWeakRange(Func<double, double, bool> cmp)
    {
        return !cmp(TestScore, ranges[(int)Enums.Border.P10]) && cmp(TestScore, ranges[(int)Enums.Border.P25]);
    }
    private bool scoreInAveragelyWeakRange(Func<double, double, bool> cmp)
    {
        return !cmp(TestScore, ranges[(int)Enums.Border.P25]) && cmp(TestScore, ranges[(int)Enums.Border.P50]);
    }
    private bool scoreInAveragelyGoodRange(Func<double, double, bool> cmp)
    {
        return !cmp(TestScore, ranges[(int)Enums.Border.P50]) && cmp(TestScore, ranges[(int)Enums.Border.P75]);
    }
    private bool scoreInGoodRange(Func<double, double, bool> cmp)
    {
        return !cmp(TestScore, ranges[(int)Enums.Border.P75]) && cmp(TestScore, ranges[(int)Enums.Border.P90]);
    }
    private bool scoreInVeryGoodRange(Func<double, double, bool> cmp)
    {
        return (TestScore == ranges[(int)Enums.Border.P90]) || !cmp(TestScore, ranges[(int)Enums.Border.P90]);
    }

}
```

However, as noted in the added comment, you can now use a different comparison function, that is, swap your `<` for a `>`.

Comment: Wow! You guys got into my problem really fast!

In the end I got to the same answer as you did. Incredible those delegates.

My biggest problem was asking the right questions :)

I swapped the comparisons in the inheriting classes as they exist specific for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

`System.Double` implements [`IComparable<double>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). So, if you have several lines of code, that differs only with comparison operator, you can write something like this:

```
abstract class ComparisonBase
{
    protected bool IsSatisfiesCondition(double left, double right, params int[] conditions)
    {
        return conditions.Contains(left.CompareTo(right));
    }

    public abstract bool Compare(double left, double right);
}

class GreaterThan : ComparisonBase
{
    public override bool Compare(double left, double right)
    {
        // instead of left > right
        return IsSatisfiesCondition(left, right, 1);
    }
}

class LessThan : ComparisonBase
{
    public override bool Compare(double left, double right)
    {
        // instead of left < right
        return IsSatisfiesCondition(left, right, -1);
    }
}

class GreaterThanOrEqual : ComparisonBase
{
    public override bool Compare(double left, double right)
    {
        // instead of left >= right
        return IsSatisfiesCondition(left, right, 1, 0);
    }
}
```

This is just sample, but it should give you an idea how to apply it in your real code.

Comment: this probably works, but I went with the delegates and lambda functions on my own. I cannot give the votes to you both - that is a shame!

Comment: Note that `CompareTo` may return any integer, not just `-1`, `0`, `1`, so your solution would probably not work as expected without modification, see [MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43hc6wht%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @Lucero: Yes, in general, comparison result must be wrapped into `Math.Sign`. But for primitive types like `double` there will be -1, 0, 1, AFAIK.

Comment: I checked the reference source and you're indeed right for the `double` class, but I'd not assume this to always be or remain true nevertheless, e.g. other (Mono etc.) or future implementations might not stick to these tree distinct values.